# CSS give child element the same background as Grandparent. Grand Parent's background is set by Javascript

Tags: css, inheritance, responsive-design

This may only be possible in JS. I am working on a responsive design for a page.  I need a child element to have the same background-image as it's parent ONLY if the the max-width is 768px.  The caveat is that the background image of the parent is set by JavaScript based on what the person clicked on.

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    // background-image: inherit from grandparent?
}
```

Comment: `background-image: inherit`

Answer (score 5):

To inherit the value of a property from the parent element, you can use the [`inherit`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#valdef-all-inherit) keyword:

> If the [cascaded value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascaded-value) of a property is the [`inherit`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#valdef-all-inherit)
>   keyword, the [inherited value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherited-value) becomes the property’s
>   [specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#specified-value) and [computed values](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#computed-value).

```
background-image: inherit;
```

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#target'),
    bg = 'linear-gradient(to right, #ff0 33%, #0ff 33%, #0ff 66%, #f0f 66%)';
el.style.backgroundImage = bg;
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px 20%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  p {
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-image: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="target"><p>Hello</p></div>
```

If you want to inherit from an ancestor multiple levels up, you can use `inherit` on all of them, but the result might be undesirable:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#target'),
    bg = 'linear-gradient(to right, #ff0 33%, #0ff 33%, #0ff 66%, #f0f 66%)';
el.style.backgroundImage = bg;
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px 20%;
  background-image: inherit;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  p {
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-image: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="target"><div><div><p>Hello</p></div></div></div>
```

Or, if [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) is not a problem, you can use CSS variables:

```js
el.style.setProperty('--bg', bg);
```

```css
background-image: var(--bg);
```

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#target'),
    bg = 'linear-gradient(to right, #ff0 33%, #0ff 33%, #0ff 66%, #f0f 66%)';
el.style.setProperty('--bg', bg);
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px 20%;
}
#target {
  background-image: var(--bg);
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  p {
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-image: var(--bg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="target"><div><div><p>Hello</p></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Okay, is there anywhere to inherit it from an element... multiple levels up?  Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @Iscariot You can use inherit on all levels

Comment: The parent has no background, it's just a container for display: flex, but I need this child to have it's grandparents background.

Comment: I tested it, and in my test it just blanked the background entirely.

Comment: @Oriol How bad is the support on that?

Comment: Okay IE does not support that at all.  Very neat example.  Thank you for answering.

Comment: @abluejelly `inherit` doesn't grab from multiple elements up. That's because the parent always has a [specified value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#specified-value), which in case there is no [cascaded value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascaded-value) will be the [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial-value) (for non-inheritable properties). `inherit` will grab that specified value of the parent.

Comment: Okay,  I can set the background-image in the JS.  There is a gradient there normally, is there anyway to hide the background image until it reaches that media?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean